# Delete deployment package for lambda version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I had made a lambda function in the past which I want to change. At the time of making it there were no layers, so I was forced to use a deployment package. I have published this version under an alias, and would like to modify the $latest version .

However, in the $latest version, which is editable, the only code entry types available are zip and S3, the code editor is not there. How can I remove the deployed package so I can use a layer with some libraries, and write the code into the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to create a new lambda, enter your code in the editor and then export the function as a zip file. Then just go over to your original lambda and upload this zip file. You can delete the new lambda you created after you do this.

Comment: I would like to avoid this, as it means going through this process every time I want to make a change.

Comment: If you do this once, you will be able to edit the code directly in the browser as your package size will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a zip file of your code only and upload it using 'upload a zip file'. This will replace your existing package with a smaller code file that can me edited via online editor. NOTE: only zip your lambda_function.py file and nothing else. Rest you can upload via layers as you said.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).